# Writing class file

Tags: documentclass-writing, compilation-error, letterhead

I am trying to learn how to write a class file. I know it is not going to be easy, but I am determined to learn that skill. What I did was to choose a simple document to create, namely, a personal letterhead. What I needed to do was to put a "head" at the top. So, I created that with LaTeX and looked for a way to add this to the letter class in such a way that it could be used by anyone (which, naturally, is the purpose of creating a letterhead class). So, the things to be added in the "head", such as name, designation, office address, house address, etc. are to be added when compiling the letter. I, therefore, created a command \makehead that is expected to create two minipages at the top of the paper and add all the details that I had added in the sample I had created using LaTeX in just the same manner. Then I tried to build a letter using this class file, but it failed with the error: 
Argument of @undeclaredcolor has an extra }.
 
                \par
followed by a line from the tex file. The cls file is rather simple and is given below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mylh}[2020/06/26 Class file for my letterhead]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{letter}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{letter}[2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class]
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia,xltxtra}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.7,0.2,0.2}
\newcommand{\makehead}[5]{%
\begin{minipage}{9cm}
\textsf{#1,\\ #2, \\ \\ #3, \\ }
\end{minipage}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{5.7cm}
\vspace*{40pt}\raggedleft{\huge\textsf{\textbf{\color[red}\MakeUpperCase #4}}\\
\vspace*{-8pt}\textcolor{black}{\small{\textsf{#5}}}
\end{minipage}}
```

I wonder if my approach itself is correct and also if the syntax is correct. I am unable to understand why the error says undeclared color when a color is defined and also why it complains about an extra closing brace.

As suggested bt  David Carlisle, I am appending a sample tex file using this class:

```
\documentclass{mylh}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xltxtra}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\begin{document}
\makehead{{blah}{address1\\ address2,\\ address3}{Address1,\\ Address2,\\ Address3}{My Name}{all. my. degrees.}}
\begin{letter}

\end{letter}
```

When I compile this I get the error: Runaway argument?
{{blah}{address1\ address2,\ address3}{Address1,\ Address2,\ Addr\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
 
                   \par 
and there is no document. I hope this helps to identify the error. I have corrected an error of a left brace pointed out by Sigur earlier.

Thank you once again.
\end{document}

Thank you in advance for any clue to a solution.

Comment: There is a typo: `\color[red}`. It should be `\color{red}`.

Comment: you are missing a } at the end, but also if asking about an error please provide a small test file that shows the error (a document that calls this class and just does begin document end document does not generate an error about colors